# how we fill data table with file byte array in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

First i create data table with single column of type `system.byte[]` and insert byte array from `FileUploader`  by using `FileUploader.FileByte` and in last when i want convert byte array in to file I use `File.WriteAllBytes()` in this i give path where i store file with new file name and byte array?

```
if (ViewState["datAdminDocument"] == null)// if data table id null
{
    datAdminDocument = new DataTable();  //add new column in data table
    datAdminDocument.Columns.Add("FileBytes", typeof(System.Byte[]));  //column for file byte array System.Byte[] is use fro byte array
    ViewState["datAdminDocument"] = datAdminDocument;// viewstate use for prevent the data in datatable 
}
else
{
    datAdminDocument = ViewState["datAdminDocument"] as DataTable;  // if data table is not null then else condition execute
}

    DataRow drow = null;// drow is a null object for datarow  
    drow = datAdminDocument.NewRow();
    drow[0] = AdminFileUpload.FileBytes;  //file byte array insert in data table row
    datAdminDocument.Rows.Add(drow);  //add row in data table
    datAdminDocument.AcceptChanges();  //change in data table
    GridAdminUploadDocument.DataSource = datAdminDocument;//data table bind with gird
    GridAdminUploadDocument.DataBind();
    ViewState["datAdminDocument"] = datAdminDocument;  // after that now i want retrive byte array form data table by using for loop
     for (i = 0; i < datAdminDocument.Rows.Count; i++)  //for loop use for retrive byte array from data table column.
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/AdminDocument/a.jpg"),
            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(datAdminDocument.Rows[i][0].ToString().Trim());
     }  // a.jpg is a new file name
```

Comment: What happens, when you are debugging your code? Compile errors? Exceptions?

Comment: In designation folder file is transfer but it not open

Comment: What have you tried to open the file?

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/AdminDocument/a.jpg"),
            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(datAdminDocument.Rows[i][0].ToString().Trim());

Comment: You cannot use `File.WriteAllBytes` to open a file... From msdn `Creates a new file, writes the specified byte array to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten. `  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd188170.aspx

Comment: Sir I do all things but i can not get the result please see my code and provide me solution and code for result

Comment: I don't understand the question. The title is about getting the byte array into a DataTable, but it looks like the code already does that? Then you save that data to a file. So what's the issue exactly?

Comment: first i want to store file byte array in data table. File byte array come from file upload through file bytes property.and last Retrive File byte array from data table and convert into file

Comment: well your code already does those steps...so what's the problem? Is some part of it not working? If so, please describe any exceptions you get, and/or any step which does not behave as you expected (describe what actually happens vs what you wanted to happen)

Comment: problem is this  file  come in designation folder but it  can not open

Comment: What happens when you try to open it? Any error message? Are you opening it through code, or just yourself in the Windows Explorer? Please learn to provide actual details of your problem and how to reproduce it, otherwise I have to keep asking basic questions. Saying nothing except "it's not working" or "it can't open" does not help me to help you. I cannot see your screen or read your mind :-)

Comment: not any error. I open the file from window Explorer it cannot open.In Window Explorer file can not come in proper format